# git push origin master não esta funcionando

Tags: git, github

Estou fazendo o seguinte fluxo:

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "teste"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/Brininhoxd/teste.git
git push -u origin main
```

quando dou o `git push -u origin main` ele fica carregando pra sempre e não acontece nada, alguém consegue me ajudar

Comment: Você está colocando seu usuário e senha do Github?

Comment: então, o problema é justamente esse, ele não aparece a opção de mandar, ele simplesmente fica parado, como se tivesse fazendo algum processo, só que não acaba

Comment: você importou a chave ssh ?... pode  estar carregando pela chave ssh importada a sua conta.

Answer (score 0):

Bruno,

Tente da seguinte forma:

substitua `git push origin main` por `git push origin master`